# WordPress registration auto login and custom redirection

Tags: php, wordpress

I want my users to register, auto login and get redirected to the link thrown by the user in the header like `www.example.com/register/?redirect_to=/to/some/link&reauth=1`

I have made a file in `\wp-content\plugins\theme-my-login-custom.php`

the code is as follows:-

```
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']))
    {
        wp_redirect( '/'.$_REQUEST['redirect_to'] );
    }
    else
    wp_redirect( '/profile' );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
```

The auto login is working fine but I cant catch the variable `redirect_to` **to redirect to the requested page**..

any help will be appreciated..

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use appropriate hook for this. Try https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_redirect.

**UPDATE2:**

Add this line into your registration form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/link/to/location/">
```

where value is your destination page.

Comment: And could you add '<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/link/to/location/">' into registration form? And fill the value instead of sending it through url and proccess it manually. Please describe how you've created your registration form.